# When you "love somebody so much"

Tags: idioms, expressions, phrases

I am looking for some fixed American expressions / idiom to convey my love to someone in an exaggerated way! I was wondering whether the following structures can be used in this sense:

> **a.** I love you **to pieces**. (I think this construction is reserved for missing someone.) 
> **b.** I love you **to the moon and back**. 
> **c** I love you **to death**.

I know that "b" works here properly, but first please let me know if "a" is off here as I think.
Then I am wide open to any other interchangeable idiom / expression which can substitute for "to the moon and back" and for "to death" especially in AmE.

Comment: There are any number of quirky "intensifier" phrases that might follow assertions like ***I love you, We're screwed, I'll beat you,*** etc. One that I've always quite liked, which is obviously still "current", is here on YouTube with [Blackberry Smoke Performs *I'm Gonna Love You **Six Ways From Sunday***.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLeuHuvVSFk)

Comment: Interestingly, although we do it with *I'll knock / beat / kick him **from here to next week / kingdom come / into a cocked hat...***, I can't think of any such phrase after ***I hate you/him*** (for my money, ***I hate him to bits*** is "non-idiomatic").

Comment: ...the *only* quirky intensifier I can think of after ***I hate him*** is so common it no longer sounds particularly "quirky" anyway. [*I hate him **with a vengeance***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hate+him+with+a+vengeance%22) is more "cliched" than "syntactically quirky".

Answer (score 1):

You can use any idiom that you have posted, here are examples from books.

- *to the moon and back*:

Karen Kingsbury (American). **To the Moon and Back: A Novel**.

> Love you to the moon and back, Brady.

---

- *to pieces*:

Suzanne Kamata (American). **Love You to Pieces: Creative Writers on Raising a Child with Special Needs**.

---

- *in the worst way*:

Doris Johnson. **Precious Heart**.

> I want to love you in the worst way, and it's killing me.

---

- *to death*:

Amy Garvey. **I Love You To Death**.

---

- *so bad one can taste it*

---

- *something fierce*:

Jean Rattay. **The Kirkfield Heiress**.

> There are times when a man and a woman love each other something fierce, but they are both so stubborn that they just keep buttin' heads like the rams in the field, to see who can butt the hardest and for no other reason.